# Admin panel and user login in firebase and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I want to use one login form for admin and a user in my project for react js and firebase,only the admin to be able to login and be redirected to the admin panel and the user to the user profile with,

How can i implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for implementing such a role-based access control system is to use [Custom Claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).

You will combine Custom Claims (and [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth)) together with Firebase Security Rules. As explained in the doc referred to above:

> The Firebase Admin SDK supports defining custom attributes on user accounts. This provides the ability to implement various access
> control strategies, including role-based access control, in Firebase
> apps. These custom attributes can give users different levels of
> access (roles), which are enforced in an application's security rules.

Once you'll have assigned to your users a Custom Claim corresponding to their user role (e.g. Admin or "simple" user), you will be able to:

- Adapt your Security Rules according to the claims;
- [Get the Claim in your front-end](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#access_custom_claims_on_the_client) and act accordingly (e.g. redirected to the admin panel or to the user profile)

---

You may be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which presents "How to create an Admin module for managing users access and roles" which shows how to use [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to assign the Claims *(disclaimer, I'm the author)*.

Comment: Hi @sage, did you have the time to look at the proposed solution?